# Passing an argument to a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a button which adds a paragraph each time it is clicked. In my code i have a function called `addPara(count)`, and i have a `counterstart` variable. how can i pass this `counterstart` variable to me function?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are doing now and what you need. This question is hard to understand.

Answer (score 4):

`addPara(counterstart);`

Comment: thanks but not what i needed perhaps my question is too vague. The addPara() function should have (at least) one argument passed to it – the counterStart variable....

Comment: Yeah, I'm passing the `counterstart` variable to `addPara`.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you're not sure how many arguments will be passed, you can reference any and all argument via the `arguments` collection inside the function.

```
function addPara() {
    console.log(arguments); // "arguments" is a collection of the arguments.
    if(arguments[0] === undefined) { 
         // do something and return if no arguments were given
        return false;
    }
      // otherwise loop through the arguments passed
    for( var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++ ) {
       // do something with arguments[ i ];
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is so ambiguous that I question if its even worth answering. +1 for the effort.